# html, javascript code works perfectly on my pc browser but not on my windows phone app

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, winjs, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to make a windows phone 8.1 app that send a get request using html5 css and javascript. the only problem is the my code works on my browser but when I build the app using visual studio the get request is sent only the first time. I have no clue why this happens.
The code for the page is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("button").click(function()
        {
         $.get("http://192.168.1.100/gpio/0")
        });
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send GET request </button>

</body>
</html>
```

The code that I use for the app is the same with just a few changes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>App1</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- App1 references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.get("http://192.168.1.100/gpio/0")
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send GET request</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your phone and your PC connected to same lan?

Comment: this is the address of a wifi module(esp8266) which in this case is programmed to be a server. in fact the app works but just once, just the first time i press the button.

Comment: Check if the webrequest cache is responsible for this behavior. The [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8dab5969-d97b-4817-9572-6e19a4d95f2c/how-to-disable-caching-in-a-winjsxhr-request?forum=winappswithhtml5) might help.

Comment: @Jagannath thanks man. that was the prob